# Kuberenetes MongoDB agent config for log rotation

Tags: mongodb

Kubernetes MongoDB agent config for log rotation.

version: `mongodb-kubernetes-operator:0.8.3`

Inside this folder the logs go: `/var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/`
I can see readiness.log and mongodb.log.

It's rotating the `mongodb.log` file just fine. But I'm not sure it's rotating the `readiness.log` file, which is causing me to run out of space.

Is it supposed to rotate it?
Can I add a setting in the config to include all log files in the folder?
I'm assuming the systemLog.path is where logs should go, not what files to be rotated.

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
...
...
  agent:
    logFile: automation-agent.log
    logLevel: "0"
    logRotate:
      includeAuditLogsWithMongoDBLogs: true
      numTotal: 2
      numUncompressed: 0
      sizeThresholdMB: "500"
      timeThresholdHrs: 24
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: false
      path: /var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb.log
```